# How to efficiently execute multiple SQL queries with the same WHERE clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I'd like to do multiple SQL queries that share the same `WHERE` clause. My queries all involve counting the number of entries in various groups. At the moment I'm executing each query separately, which presumably is causing the `WHERE` filter to be applied many times. This seems wasteful. Is there any way for me to combine my queries together such that the `WHERE` clause is invoked only once?  More generally, is there any way to make the queries below more efficient?

Specifically, let's say I've got a table of public figures.

**PublicFigures**

```
last_name | occupation   | age   | state | has_dogs
---------------------------------------------------
Stewart   | comedian     |  51   | NY    | true
Colbert   | comedian     |  49   | NJ    | false
Obama     | president    |  52   | DC    | true
Romney    | consultant   |  66   | CA    | true
(etc..)
```

I'd like to extract two types of information from the table. First, I'd like counts of how often each last_name appears with each occupation, and second, I'd like data on dog ownership by state. In both cases I'm only interested in public figures under the age of 55. Thus, both queries use the same `WHERE` clause.

The first query, for names and occupations, looks like this

```
SELECT last_name, occupation, COUNT(*) as count WHERE age < 55 FROM "PublicFigures" GROUP BY last_name, occupation
```

and gives this

```
last_name | occupation   | count
---------------------------------
Stewart   | comedian     |  1   
Stewart   | president    |  0
Colbert   | comedian     |  1 
Colbert   | president    |  0
Obama     | comedian     |  0
Obama     | president    |  1
```

The second query is this:

```
SELECT state, has_dogs, COUNT(*) as count WHERE age < 55 FROM "PublicFigures" GROUP BY state, has_dogs


state | has_dogs | count
---------------------------------------------------
NY    | true     | 1
NY    | false    | 0
NJ    | true     | 0
NJ    | false    | 0
DC    | true     | 1
DC    | false    | 1
```

Is there a way to get these results that's more efficient than by these two queries separately? Could the two queries be combined somehow?

In real life, of course, my table is bigger, I have more queries, and my filtering condition is more complex. I think the savings I could garner from smarter SQL are substantial. I'd especially appreciate solutions in Rails3-friendly ActiveRecord, if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: having two relatively simple queries is better than one very complex query.

Comment: huh. ok. That may be true. Not the answer I was expecting, but you may be right! Thanks.

Comment: an alternative would be the counts via window functions, i.e. over(partition by ..) instead of grouping but I agree with Sam D in avoiding very complex queries when possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you can just make each query faster on a standalone basis by creating an index, for example, that would be your best bet.  If not, then create a temporary table and then query it repeatedly instead of the original:

```
create temporary table young_figures as 
    select * from public_figures where age < 55;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where an index will do wonders. Another approach that can be combined with the creation of indexes is filter once select many times. Hopefully this will buy you something , but the correct indexes may be all you need.

```
CREATE INDEX pidx_public_figures_age ON public_figures (age)
WHERE age < 55;
--Try temp table with the index and also try just the new index and see if all your queries now run as fast as you would hope.
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_public_figures AS
 SELECT last_name, occupation ,age, state, has_dogs 
 FROM films WHERE age < 55;
```

Now run your N number of queries either against the actual table or with the temp table approach and see which performs better under your use case

```
SELECT last_name, occupation, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM temp_public_figures
GROUP BY last_name, occupation;

SELECT state, has_dogs, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM temp_public_figures
GROUP BY state, has_dogs;
```

Comment: Take special note of that partial index under the right data distribution they work wonders. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-partial.html